# Refactoring a class which inherited from a std::container

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've a medium chunk of code containing 5 classes that they're all inherited from standard containers. For example:

```
class Step : public std::vector<unsigned int>
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Step& step);
    Step& operator =(const Step& rhv);
    static Step fromString(const std::string &input);
    std::string name;
};
```

I know it's a bad idea to inherit from standard containers, so I'm going to remove all inheritances by adding a subobject of parent datatype:

```
class Step
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Step& step);
    Step& operator =(const Step& rhv);
    static Step fromString(const std::string &input);
    std::string name;
    // std::vector interface:
    inline std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator begin() const {return data.begin();}
    inline std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator end() const {return data.end();}
    inline size_t size() const {return data.size();}
    typedef std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator const_iterator;
private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> data;
};
```

I'm doing this because the code is widely used in other programs and changing structure is very costly.

And question: what do you suggest to revise the code by small changes? (as less as possible)

**Clarification:**
I have a some classes inherited from stl containers. And there are lots of codes using them. My question is that how do I remove that evil inheritance without changing codes using those classes?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Please clarify...

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: Since you have access to the data from outside the class by means of the iterators, you do not need friendship (and should avoid it). Related suggestion: Are those the only operations that are used from your class? (read-only begin/end/size?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I don't know which operations are used by clients. The only known fact is that the class itself should be treated as a `std::vector<unsigned int>`. So all operations of a standard vector should be available in the class.

Comment: You can't remove the inheritance without changing the class definitions. You have to, one way or the other, add the methods used by your system. If it was me, I would remove inheritance one class at a time, rebuild the project, and add the methods the compiler/linker complains about.

Comment: @Joachim: I don't have access to all codes written by others. I don't know how them use `Step`, however I'm obliged to give them a new static library...

Comment: Given the information that you are providing in the comments, the most sensible thing is to actually *design* what the class should do, and *should behave like a vector* is not an option. Without having access to the user code, you cannot make a non-breaking change other than reimplementing the whole vector interface by forwarding, and that is really not much better than what you have. If you are going to make a breaking change, then **design** and offer a sensible interface of what users should be able to do with `Step` and distribute the new lib with a HUGE warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution: making the inheritance private (or protected, if it makes sense), and `using` the relevant members:

```
class Step : private std::vector<int>
{
    typedef std::vector<int> base_;

public:
    using base_::operator[];
    using base_::size;
    ...

};
```

If inheritance indeed made the code simpler, then you may like this solution. The real problem with inheriting from containers is that the conversion to `vector` may get you in trouble once you add members to the `Step` class: the destructor changes, and you know, it's not virtual in the first place. Private inheritance solves this problem.

Comment: Sounds like the best possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I know it's a bad idea to inherit from standard containers

It makes sense in many scenarios. If you think that it is **always** a bad idea, then you're mistaken. If inheriting from standard container makes your code shorted and easier to read, then inheriting from STL container is a good idea. In **MY** opinion your first class (that inherits std::vector) is better than second one.

> And question: what do you suggest to revise the code by small changes?

If you want to waste your time just for the heck of it...

For a start you could remove "public friend" function which doesn't make any sense.

After that declare several typedefs.

```
typedef std::string Name;

class Step{
protected:
    typedef std::vector<int> Data;
    Data data;
public:
    typedef Data::const_iterator ConstIterator;
    Step& operator=(const Step& other);
    static Step fromString(const std::string &input);
    Name name;
    ConstIterator begin() const;
    ConstIterator end() const;
    size_t size() const;
};
```

And use those typedeffed types in all code that interacts with Step. This way you will be able to change internal types later (for example, replace std::vector with std::deque, or implement custom iterator class) without having to modify entire project.

Comment: As far as I know standard containers don't have a virtual destructor, so soesn't this cause undefined behavior in some situations?

Comment: @sorush-r: I agree with SigTerm in that this does not mean that you cannot inherit standard container classes in the simplest cases (and I know some situations where it simplifies matters). The real problems arise when someone in your team adds members to the class. Ergo, in situations where the source code is shared, coding conventions *should* prevent people from inheriting containers.

Comment: @sorush-r: "no virtual destructor" is not a problem as long as you don't delete objects using pointer to base class (i.e. `std:;vector<X>` or something). In majority of scenarios this (deleting using pointer to base) is not necessary. You could easily use class (derived from container) as a non-pointer member variable. I think that shouldn't be much of a problem to add virtual destructor to the derived class. Of course, that won't prevent somebody determined enough from casting your derived class back into `std::vector`, but I'm not certain why would somebody want to do that in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to first refactor your functionality as free functions:

```
namespace Step2 {
  std::vector<unsigned int> fromString(const std::string &input);
}
```

and then provide a standalone header for the old API:

```
  DEPRECATED class Step : public std::vector<unsigned int>
  {
    public:
    inline static Step fromString(std::string const& input);
    {
      return Step(Step2::fromString(input));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned int> data_t;
data_t data;
```

Introducing typedef simplifies all signature of methods and reduces risk of vector's type changes

Comment: And what about unsupported operations?

Comment: What do you mean on "unsupported"?

Comment: There are some variables and methods in `Step` class that they're not in `vector`.

Comment: @sorush-r you correctly aggregate vector by class Step, if you need these variables and methods - use it!