# How to get a non-const iterator while using a const "this" pointer?

Tags: c++, casting, constants, this

My problem is the use of const_cast<>. I have a class which inherits from vector. Now in one of its member functions when I use `this->begin()`, `this` being a const  pointer, it returns a constant iterator but I want to obtain a non-const iterator. The code looks something like ...

```
class xyz : private std::vector<//something>
{
public:
 xyz();
 void doSomething();
}

void doSomething()
{
    xyz::iterator it;
    it = this->begin();
    *it.insert(something); //here is the problem and this where I need to use const_cast 
                           // and in a lot more places
}
```

In the above function, since `this->begin()` returns a const iterator, I am forced to use a constant iterator and do a typecasting whenever I need to insert an element.

I thought of using const_cast at this->begin() but my friend told me that it is a bad idea to remove the constness of the `this` pointer. If it is so, then what is the way around?

Comment: Actually, You opened a can of worms with *I have a class which inherits from vector*, Why do you inherit from `std::vector`? It is not meant for Inheritance.

Comment: @Als : necessity i need a class which inherits from vector so that class itself acts as a vector and can you be more specific about why it is not a good idea to inherit i am new so please help me.

Comment: [Why should not I subclass/inherit standard containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/why-should-not-i-subclass-inherit-standard-containers) You should use containershipp rather than Inheritance.

Comment: @Als :well i am bound to use it that way, but is there a solution to the const_cast problem i am facing?

Comment: @Als: " It is not meant for Inheritance." [Nonsense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667292/refactoring-a-class-which-inherited-from-a-stdcontainer/9669406#9669406). There are situations when it is useful. "no virtual destructors" won't cause problems as long as don't delete derived class using pointer to vector (there's no reason to that anyway).

Comment: It's sometimes valid to inherit privately from a standard container, but certainly never publicly.  If you want a class that acts as a vector, then you have one: `std::vector`.  If you want a class with slightly different semantics, you can define one.  If you want a class which has some of the functionality of vector, but does other things differently, it's possible to inherit privately, and use `using` to hoist the functionality you want up into the derived class.

Comment: @SigTerm: I am sorry for the reasons mentioned in-plenty in the answer I linked above, I do not agree to your (invalid)contention & No I won't call your contention *Nonesense*, eventhough it is because you are free to have your (Incorrect)opinions, it's a free world.

Comment: @Als: The answer you linked contains highly debatable personal belief that is not convincing. In practice not every class needs virtual destructor and for every feature people try to avoid there's specific situation when this feature is useful. Same applies to inheriting from containers.

Comment: Aside from the std::vector public inheritance issue, the const_cast issue seems unconnected to your code. Can you provide a small code sample that reproduces the problem? Also, there is a non-const std::vector<T>::begin() method returning iterator.

Comment: @SigTerm: "won't cause problems as long as don't delete derived class using pointer to vector". And how do you know that your fellow programmers or users of your API won't do this? My opinion is that its  better to avoid any chances of object slicing.

Comment: @Rolle: "And how do you know" And how do you know that "your fellow programmers" won't static_cast it into something like char* and `delete[]` it? It is said that determined fool can break any system that is said to be fool-proof. Sane usage is safe. Unsafe usage requires dangerous design decisions, and if your colleagues use something that deletes standard containers by pointers, you're screwed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If the vector is part of the state of the class, either as a member or
as a base (although it's really bad practice to publicly inherit from
`vector`), then a `const` member function should not modify it.  If the
vector is part of the state, and a function modifies it, the function
should not be const.

Generally.  There are special cases where, for example, the vector
represents cached state, that is logically calculated, but whose
calculation is expensive.  In such cases, you can make the vector a
mutable member.  But do be sure that the vector really doesn't represent
"observable state".

And finally, the code you post doesn't seem to have anything to do with
the problem.  For starters, the only function is non-const.  And the 
code won't compile, for several reasons (use of `this` in a non-member
function, invocation of a member function `insert` on an iterator, which
doesn't have such a member, etc.).